# Copy from VB.NET DataGridView into Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

I'm trying to copy from a `DataGridView` control and paste into `Excel`.  The copy works, but the `cell widths` remain narrow and my data isn't formatted properly.  Even highlighting the column and attempting to `auto-size` doesn't work.  Is there something I can do in my grid control to make this work better?

VS2013
VB.NET
Framework 4.5.2

Edit:
It's a `DataGridView` with all the defaults. It's loaded from a `DataSet` with this statement:

```
grid.DataSource = _gridData.Tables(0) 
(where grid is the DataGridView and _gridData is the DataSet)
```

Comment: `Even highlighting the column and attempting to auto-size doesn't work` its hard to say why when you did not post any code. Please update your question ***with specifics*** so we can help you. Posting a question ***without code*** is like asking a doctor what's wrong with you if he hasn't seen you.

Comment: It's a DataGridView with all the defaults.  It's loaded from a DataSet with this statement: grid.DataSource = _gridData.Tables(0) (where grid is the DataGridView and _gridData is the DataSet).

Comment: Are you copying row by row from datagridview to excel? Post code. Since is copying nicely post code for auto-size. Are copying into merged columns? We need more info to be able to help you

Comment: The answer is to do the paste differently into Excel.  All of these work for me: right-click "Paste:Match Destination Formatting", Paste Special (Unicode Text or Text).